# ORA-00933 runtime plsql throwing the error

Tags: plsql

I am trying to query the dba_tables, if table "SPLIT_EXT_INFO" not present i am getting correct output, if table "SPLIT_EXT_INFO" exist i am getting below error,

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    t_cnt         NUMBER;
    v_schema_name VARCHAR2(40) := 'DBA';
    v_table_name  VARCHAR2(40) := 'SPLIT_EXT_INFO';
    refcur        SYS_REFCURSOR;
    split_mapper  VARCHAR2(40);
    info_tab      VARCHAR2(40);
    tracker       VARCHAR2(40);
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(1)
    INTO   t_cnt
    FROM   dba_tables
    WHERE  owner = v_schema_name
           AND table_name = v_table_name;

    dbms_output.Put_line(t_cnt);

    IF t_cnt = 0 THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line('NO_SPLIT_TAB');
    ELSE
      OPEN refcur FOR 'SELECT  split_mapper, info_tab, tracker FROM '
                      ||v_schema_name
                      ||'.'
                      ||v_table_name
                      || 'where nodename = ''host1.world.com''';

      LOOP
          FETCH refcur INTO split_mapper,info_tab,tracker;
          EXIT WHEN refcur%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_output.Put_line(split_mapper
                               ||':'
                               ||info_tab
                               ||':'
                               ||tracker);
      END LOOP;
      IF refcur%rowcount = 0 THEN
        dbms_output.Put_line('NO_SPLIT_ENTRY');
      END IF;
    END IF;
    CLOSE refcur;
END;
/
```

Error:

```
1
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 21
```

can someone add help in this, thanks !

Regards
Kannan

Comment: Please update the question with another ORA code. It should be ORA-00933 not the 6512. The purpose of 6512 is just to display a line where error occurs. The "main" error message is "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apostrophe symbol is on a wrong place before WHERE clause is being concatenated

```
your code: || 'where nodename = ''host1.world.com''';
right is : ||' where nodename = ''host1.world.com''';
```

In your version the sql will look like

```
select ... FROM tableWHERE nomename = ...
```

The missing space symbol between table name and WHERE causing this problem